# How can I detect when page has been rendered with PDFJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, pdf.js

Once PDF.JS has **completed rendered** each page, I want to **then** do a find/replace on the contents of that page.

I invoke PDF.JS by putting the following in a document in an iFrame:

```
<script>
fileId=0;
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
var fileId = getURLParameter("fileId");
var DEFAULT_URL = '/viewer/fetchpdf.php?fileId='+fileId;
</script>
```

and then setting the URL from the parent frame:

```
url = '/_third_party/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?fileId='+$(this).attr('href');
$("#iframeViewPdf").attr('src', url);
```

I've noticed when using PDF.JS to render a PDF, it initialises each page with a loading placeholder:

```
<div id="pageContainer3" class="page" style="width: 991px; height: 1319px;">
    <div class="loadingIcon"></div>
</div>
<div id="pageContainer4...
```

It then renders the PDF as html, e.g.

```
<div id="pageContainer3" class="page" style="width: 991px; height: 1319px;">
    <div class="canvasWrapper" style="width: 991px; height: 1319px;">
        <canvas id="page46" width="991" height="1319" style="width: 991px; height: 1319px;">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="textLayer" style="width: 991px; height: 1319px;">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pageContainer4...
```

Answer (score 1):

With the clarification, it is a very different story. You are not using PDF.JS directly, but their web wrapper. One thing that I think you can use (I've never done it, just reading the code now) is the fact that they are emitting `pageRendered` event on the `document`, so if you can add a listener to it, you should be fine:

```
var frameDoc = document.getElementById('iframeViewPdf').contentWindow.document;

frameDoc.addEventListener('pagerendered', function (evt) {
  console.log(evt); // see what goodies hide here! like page number etc
}
```

(Didn't test, might need tweaking.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. Solution was missing the last parenthesis.

Unfortunately doesn't seem to pick up any events, playing with it now to see if I can figure out why.

Comment: I found the following code worked, can you edit your answer to reflect this?

    $( "#iframeViewPdf" ).load(function() { // wait for iframe to load
        var frameDoc = $("#iframeViewPdf").contents()[0];
        frameDoc.addEventListener("pagerendered", function (evt) {
            console.log(evt.detail);
        });
    });

Answer (score 1):

So this is how we can detect the rendering of a page. It's important to wait for the iframe contents to load before setting up the listener.

```
$( "#iframeViewPdf" ).load(function() { // wait for iframe to load
    var frameDoc = $("#iframeViewPdf").contents()[0];     
    frameDoc.addEventListener("pagerendered", function (evt) { 
        console.log(evt.detail);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Step 1: store a refer to the renderer
var pageRendering = page.render(renderContext);
//Step : hook into the pdf render complete event
var completeCallback = pageRendering.internalRenderTask.callback;
pageRendering.internalRenderTask.callback = function (error) {
  //Step 2: what you want to do before calling the complete method                  
  completeCallback.call(this, error);
  //Step 3: do some more stuff
};
```

Comment: If I'm reading the docs right, `page.render` returns a promise, why not `page.render(...).next(function...)`? I can't see messing with internal stuff being healthy in the long run...

Comment: @Amadan I guess you're reading the docs right, you can, and probably must, do it like that. This is just another way to achieve the same.

Comment: @Amadan - Please could you provide a little more detail, I'm not quite sure how I'd go about implementing your suggestion?

Comment: I could say the same to you :) It is uninteresting for your question what exactly PDF.JS has as the rendering result, but you completely omit the important stuff: the way you invoke it in JavaScript.

Comment: @Amadan - fair enough. I've explained how I invoke it, I set the defaulturl before using the default pdfjs implementation.

Comment: What I'm seeing with this solution is that the callback is happening when MOST of the page is rendered but it isn't totally rendered. Is there something even later that we can hook into?